# Active Directory Advanced Permissions - remove unneeded possible permissions (not grant/deny)

Tags: permissions, active-directory, windows-server

I was adjusting the advanced permissions for a user on the Active Directory / MyDomain / Users object, and found a MASSIVE list of possible permissions to be granted/denied.

A good number of them were for msExchange, which I thought had been completely removed.

Is there a way to remove all these unnecessary, Exchange-related permissions from the list? There's so many that finding the permissions I actually need to grant takes forever.

I've tried searching but all the results are just instructions on granting/denying permissions, not editing the list of possible permissions.

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You might be able to hide permissions for individual attribute types by editing their schema objects at `CN=Schema, CN=Configuration, <baseDN>` – change `isDefunct` to `TRUE` – or by unchecking "Attribute is active" in the AD Schema MMC console. (AD does not support removing attribute types from the schema after they've been added, so marking them as defunct is the closest you can get.)

You might be able to hide permission groups (extended rights) such as "Read remote-access information" by editing their directory objects at `CN=Extended-Rights, CN=Configuration, <baseDN>` – change their `validAccesses` attributes from 48 (16=read + 32=write) to 0. Although it is possible to delete an extended right entirely, it's probably a bad idea to do so (at least as long as any attribute-type schema entries reference it via their `attributeSecurityGUID` attributes).